# Unable to download firebase database to my app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to programming in swift. I am trying to make an app which downloads student data from firebase database. I am unable to get the app running. This is my JSON file:

```
{"classA":[
{
"name": "Student1",
"USN": "1DS16CS095"
},
{
"name": "student2",
"USN": "1DS16CS065"
},
{
"name":"student3",
"USN":"1DS16CS047"
}
]
}
```

This is my code to download the above JSON file and put it in tableView. Modelstudent is my class where I have my variables name and USN stored. and marksstudentlistTableViewCell is the class I am using to manipulate the labels of my prototype cell.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct StudentData {
let StudentName : String
let StudentUSN : String
}

class marksstudentlist: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

var FetchedStudentIDs = [StudentData]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var _selectedsub: Int!
var selectedsub: Int {
    get {
        return _selectedsub
    }set {
        _selectedsub = newValue
    }
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        if(classselected==0){
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("classA")
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                for students in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    let studentObject = students.value as? [String: String]
                    let studentname = studentObject?["name"]
                    let studentUSN = studentObject?["USN"]
                    let student = Modelstudent(name: studentname , USN: studentUSN)
                    self.FetchedStudentIDs.insert(StudentData(StudentName :(studentname as? String!)! , StudentUSN : (studentUSN as? String!)! ) , at: 0)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
  }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FetchedStudentIDs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "marksstudentlistcell", for: indexPath) as! marksstudentlistTableViewCell

    cell.namelbl.text = FetchedStudentIDs[indexPath.row].StudentName//    Student name comes from Firebase
    cell.USNlbl.text = FetchedStudentIDs[indexPath.row].StudentUSN
    return cell
}

    @IBAction func backbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: I am so so sorry. I have edited the code and deleted all my answers. Unfortunately I am still not able to download the data from firebase to my app. Can you help me?

Comment: okay so, I am trying to download the database from my firebase into my app and display the information in tableView cell. But for some reason it is not downloading any data and the tableview cell is empty. I am also using firebase for authentication and that is working just fine. So the problem is with downloading the data. The JSON that I am using for my app is included in the question.

Comment: hey matt, I don't think the data is downloading at all. I tried to print the downloaded data in the console but I don't see anything. Does it have to do anything with my code not working properly? This is the first time I am using firebase and I am relatively new to swift. So I apologies for asking too many questions.

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift Struct is the best way to get your firebase data inside the tableView,

**Let's Get started**

on your TableView swift file, above the class and stuff paste this

```
   Struct StudentData {
   let StudentObject : String // If it's
   let StudentName : String // It returns a string right?
   let StudentUSN : String
                   // do the others.
}
```

okay so then create a var just down below the class call it

```
var FetchedStudentIDs = [StudentData]()
```

then you got the reading method from firebase

```
     ref = Database.database().reference().child("classA")
            ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                    self.studentslist.removeAll()
                    for students in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                        let studentObject = students.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let studentname = studentObject?["name"]
                        let studentUSN = studentObject?["USN"]
                        let student = Modelstudent(name: studentname as! String?, USN: studentUSN as! String?) //storing in Modelstudent class
                        self. 
FetchedStudentIDs.insert(StudentData(studentname:StudentName as! String , studentUSN : StudentUSN as! String  ) , at: 0) // Student name comes from the struct Above, do the others as this
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData() // make sure you call this
                }
            })
```

return your tableView

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FetchedStudentIDs.count
}
```

your **CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

 cell.exampleLabel.text = FetchedStudentIDs[Indexpath.row].StudentName// Student name comes from Firebase    
    return cell
}
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: yes I have added the screenshot below. Thanks a lot for your cooperation.

Comment: mate, edit the **studentname** string to `let studentname = value?["name"] as? String ?? "Default" // default shows when it returns nill`

Comment: I am getting an ambitious reference error. I have attached the screenshot below.

Comment: Value?. Is mine, use yours it's  students.value?

Comment: I am still getting the same error :( screenshot added below

Comment: mate, edit the **studentname** string to `let studentname = students.value?["name"] as? String ?? "Default" // default shows when it returns nill`

Comment: yes I did that. But I am still getting the same error as seen in the screenshot .

Comment: There is something wrong at your end, you have to review those codes-- if you want, inbox me your view controller.swift file I will do it for you

Comment: I tried that before mate but it didn't work. I'll add the screenshot below. I have no idea why this isn't working. I am very much new to swift.

Comment: mate, i am sorry to say that, but you dont even know the basics of swift, i highly advice you to do some research on swift, its more powerful and more complicated than you think, first, approve my edit and see what i changed,

Comment: update your insert structure, `self.FetchedStudentIDs.insert(StudentData(StudentName :studentname as! String , StudentUSN : studentusn as! String  ) , at: 0) // Student name comes from the struct Above, do the others as this`

Comment: Yes I am just starting with swift, so I am weak at it. But I did try with these changes but I am getting the same error. I did paste your code but I am getting the same error. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hey, I debugged the program but I am still unable to download the data. I have edited the question with my new code.'